# Bootstrap dropdown-toggle order by

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following select

```
<select>

    <option>orderby</option> 
    <option id="select1">__1</option> 
    <option id="select2">__2</option>
    <option id="select3">__3</option>

</select>
```

and these 3 divs

```
<div class="select1 box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="select2 box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
<div class="select3 box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

with this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("id")=="select1"){
                $(".box").not(".select1").hide();
                $(".select1").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("id")=="select2"){
                $(".box").not(".select2").hide();
                $(".select2").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("id")=="select3"){
                $(".box").not(".select3").hide();
                $(".select3").show();
            }

            else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

The div displayed / hidden by changing in select menu by option
and it is working well.

Now, I want to apply this example to the following bootstrap dropdown-menu
and need to select div1 to be displayed by default.

```
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="catby btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="ion-android-apps"></i>order by<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" data-value="action" id="select1">__1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="another action" id="select2">__2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here" id="select3">__3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmedcom/5qu20yu6/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. You are just trying to replicate your drop down menu but use bootstrap to style it?

Comment: i am just want to apply the select menu to bootstrap drop down menu

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="catby btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="ion-android-apps"></i>order by<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" data-value="action" id="select1">__1</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>


instead of 

<select>
    <option id="select1">__1</option> 

</select>